# Button Submit on a form is not working jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, forms, button, mobile, submit

On the press of the button, i want to alert the two values in the two inputs. However, this is not working, the page just redirects to the main page in jquery mobile.

JS

```
$('newann').submit( function () {
    alert($('#t').val());
    alert($('#m').val());
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="newann" name="newann">
    <input type="text" id="t" placeholder="Title" />
    <input type="text" id="m" placeholder="Add more..." />
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Publish News</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Selector syntax incorrect**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).You forgot to add `#` (Assuming selecting `id`)

```
$('#newann').submit( function () {
    alert($('#t').val());
    alert($('#m').val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is wrong. It should be $('#newann') as "newann" is id of the form.

You should use .(dot) for class selector and #(hash) for id selector.